# How to connect Minikube on Hyperkit on MacBook

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, minikube, hyperkit

I'm trying to connect to Hyperkit to check containers running on this VM.

All I'm getting now is `[screen is terminating]`

Here is what I do:

```
MacBook-Pro-Karol:  ~
→ minikube start --driver=hyperkit
  minikube v1.12.3 na Darwin 10.15.6
✨  Using the hyperkit driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.12...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
  Ready! kubectl is configured to be used with "minikube".

MacBook-Pro-Karol:  ~
→ sudo screen /Users/karol/.minikube/machines/minikube/tty
Password:
[screen is terminating]

MacBook-Pro-Karol:  ~
→ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
[screen is terminating]

Cannot exec '/Users/karol/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty': Permission denied

→ sudo screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
Password:
[screen is terminating]

Cannot exec '/Users/karol/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty': Operation not permitted
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `minikube ssh` to [login](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/ssh/) in to VM that minikube runs in:

> Log into or run a command on a machine with SSH; similar to
> ‘docker-machine ssh’.

```
minikube ssh [flags]
```

and then use `docker ps` to check the running containers inside this VM:

```
$ docker ps  | grep kube-api
f53aebd26287        7e28efa976bd              "kube-apiserver --ad…"   16 minutes ago   k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system_8009646ba816631d0677c2668886baad_1
12188a523d12        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2      "/pause"                 16 minutes ago   k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-minikube_kube-system_8009646ba816631d0677c2668886baad_1
```